# Что делает useNewUrlParser?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Объясните что делает useNewUrlParser

```js
async function start(){
    try{
        await mongoose.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser:true})
        app.listen(10000)
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> By default, mongoose.connect() will print out the below warning:
>
> DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will
>   be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option {
>   useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>
> The MongoDB Node.js driver rewrote the tool it uses to parse MongoDB
>   connection strings. Because this is such a big change, they put the
>   new connection string parser behind a flag. To turn on this option,
>   pass the useNewUrlParser option to mongoose.connect() or
>   mongoose.createConnection().

[Дока?](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html)